# Is there a way to not have aws mediaconvert append automatic numbering to jpeg (file group)

Tags: amazon-web-services, frame, media, capture, aws-media-convert

Is there a way to not have media convert append automatic number to frame capture as I am only generating one frame per output.

As you can see in the image, would like to remove the .000000.jpg from the filename

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no method for modifying the naming convention for MediaConvert frame capture outputs.

From the user guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/file-group-with-frame-capture-output.html

> Because the service includes automatic numbering in the frame capture file names, you can infer all the image names from the final one. For example, if your outputFilePaths value is s3://bucket/frameoutput/file.0000036.jpg, you can infer that there are 35 other images in the same location, named file.0000001, file.0000002, and so on.

There are no special settings variables for the frame capture output type: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/list-of-settings-variables-with-examples.html